# combine 2 columns in sql table to search for full names JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have entity where I have fisrtName and lastname but in search I need to implement search for fullName. How can I combine this two fields in search in JPA

right now I have something like this:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u from Client u where u.firstName like :firstName   or u.lastName like :lastName or u.documentID like :documentID");
```

I guess it is very commonly used feature but I don't know how to do that. Please help

Comment: what is "full name" ? CONCAT(firstName, lastName, " ") ? JPQL has CONCAT. What have you tried ?

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed. `Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u from Client u where CONCAT(u.firstName, ' ',u.lastName ) like :firstName   or CONCAT(u.lastName, ' ',u.firstName ) like :lastName or u.documentID like :documentID");`  write down your answer I will mark it as ANSWER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined what is "full name". If you mean a concatenation of the two "name" fields, then you can use a construct in JPQL such as

```
CONCAT(u.firstName, ' ', u.lastName)
```

to put them together with a space in between, and that ought to give enough idea how to get the precise query needed.