# Grouping columns within entity

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-jpa, jpa-annotations

I have a table with 2 columns for phone number(area code and number). When I define entity, I can do it with 2 different variable to match column names.
However, when i use it in jparepository, I want to search with a phone number (which will be a single string of area code and number).

Is ther a way to group area code and number while defining the entity to have a single variable to hold combined data of 2 columns?

```
@Entity public class Person{ private String areaCode; private String number; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPQL CONCAT method like below to achieve that.

```
CONCAT(p.areaCode, '', p.number)
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582348/combine-2-columns-in-sql-table-to-search-for-full-names-jpa)